# Filtering on one in a many-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django

I've two objects teams and tournaments,

```
class Tournament(Base):

    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
tournament = Tournament.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('tournament_id'))

class Team(Base):

    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    tournaments = models.ManyToManyField(Tournament)
```

Now I want to filter teams in one specific tournament

```
tournament = Tournament.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('tournament_id'))
   teams = Team.objects.filter(tournament=tournament) // This doesn't work.
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
desired_tournament = Tournament.objects.get(id=1)
desired_teams = Team.objects.filter(tournaments__in=[desired_tournament])
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer to help others learn. Code only answers are considered impolite.

Comment: I'd differ slightly from that @Brian - you're right that code-only answers are discouraged, but I suspect it is mainly because the opportunity to help future readers is boosted a great deal by explanatory text.

Comment: @halfer I have since improved my standard paste-in text which I keep in a sticky.. I agree - its just how to word it.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.

```
# This doesn't work.
teams = Team.objects.filter(tournament=tournament)

# This does. Not exactly intuitive, I'll concede.
teams = Team.objects.filter(tournaments=tournament)
```